# Cloudant local cache not syncing with local couch cache. Using python-cloudant

Tags: python, django, celery, couchdb, cloudant

I am new to couch DB and cloudant. A django application is converting a pdf into image using a celery task and storing both in couch DB. But the local cloudant cache is not updating, since couch DB updation is causing by the celery task. When checking the local cache,  it's storing a previous doc object with old revision number. Remote couch DB is updating fine and not syncing with local.

Why couch updations from celery is not affecting local cache
Is anything I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

The local cache is meant to cache content to reduce unnecessary calls to the API.  It doesn't sync with the remote DB.  In this case "unnecessary" is defined by you.  If the local cache contains a stale document then you can refresh it by re-fetching the document like `my_doc.fetch()`.  Where `my_doc` is a reference to your stale cached document.